# Unable to click a button on a webpage using Selenium WebDriver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button on a specific webpage ([NLI Manuscripts](https://www.nli.org.il/en/discover/manuscripts/hebrew-manuscripts/viewerpage?vid=MANUSCRIPTS#d=%5B%5BPNX_MANUSCRIPTS990000796480205171-1,FL16795621%5D%5D) using Selenium WebDriver with Python, but have run into issues. The button has an attribute that displays the text "Next item" when hovered over.

#### Approaches I've Tried:

##### 1. Using copied full XPATH from developer mode:

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]')
button.click()
```

**Problem**: This method failed to locate the button, perhaps due to a dynamic XPATH.

##### 2. Filtering any button on the page by its title attribute:

```py
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
for btn in buttons:
    if btn.get_attribute('title') == 'Next item':
        btn.click()
        break
```

**Problem**: This method also failed to locate the button with the title "Next item".

##### 3. Selecting the 'div' area and finding the relevant child:

```py
div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="MuiPaper-root mirador85 mirador-canvas-nav mirador83 MuiPaper-elevation0"]')
button = div.find_element_by_xpath('.//button[@title="Next item"]')
button.click()
```

**Problem**: I was unable to locate the div or child button using this nested approach.

Does anyone have experience with similar issues or insights into what might be going wrong?

Comment: Please provide the manual steps the reproduce?